# Activity assignee email not being sent from webform

Tags: activities, webform-civicrm

Emails are not being sent out from a CiviCRM webform to the activity assignee. Not sure why but there is a notice in Drupal: -

Notice: Undefined index: act in wf_crm_webform_postprocess->processActivities() (line 1250 of /home/xxxxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Here is the existing issue on the old forum site actually: -http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36170.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is due to a mistyped variable name.
I've [created a bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/2502685) for this in the module's issue queue.